# How can I target every n-th element in a list but only after 3

Tags: java, math

How can I write a formula for this expression:

```
boolean showAd = (position == 3 || position == 11 || position == 19 || position == 27 || position == 35 || position == 43|| position == 51);
        if (showAd) {.....
```

I tried `position % 8 ==0` but this doesnt produce the same sequence as above

Comment: use `position - 3 % 8 == 0` instead.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel but 11 - 3 % 8 is not 0

Comment: @code578841441 he meant (position - 3) % 8 == 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
position % 8 ==0
```

by

```
position % 8 == 3
```

Comment: Sometimes a solution is this simple. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
boolean showAd = (position == 3 || position == 11 ||
    position == 19 || position == 27 || position == 35 
    || position == 43|| position == 51);
```

will be similar to

```
boolean showAd = (position - 3) % 8 == 0 // Note the parentheses

// (3 - 3) = 0 % 8 = 0
// (11 - 3) = 8 % 8 = 0
// (19 - 3) = 16 % 8 = 0
// (27 - 3) = 24 % 8 = 0
// ...
```

But is not necessary to store the boolean value in a separate variable (unless you will use it later):

```
if ((position - 3) % 8 == 0) {
   ...
}
```